# Passing a variable as parameters with polyline

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to encode a set of coordinates taken from a csv file using google's polyline.encode funcion. This function takes coordinates in the following format

```
polyline.encode([(38.5, -120.2), (40.7, -120.9), (43.2, -126.4)], 5)
```

I read every line of the csv and format and pass it to a variable and then adding brackets so that the polyline.encode can run it. However my code breaks there. Do i need to convert it to a string?

This is my for loop function which formats the coords correctly

```
filename = 'coords.csv'
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")

result = ""
for line in file:
    currentline = line.split(",")
    result += '('+currentline[1]+', '+ currentline[2]+')'+','
coords = f'[{result}]'
print(coords)
```

which then prints the coordinates
Then i try to call

```
  polyline.encode(coords)
```

and my script breaks

EDIT: the polyline requires me to give the coordinate sin tuple format

```
:param coordinates: List of coordinate tuples, e.g. [(0, 0), (1, 0)].
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the a list composed of the `Tuple` data type and right now you're just using a string formatted to look like an list of `Tuple` elements.

Try this:

```
filename = 'coords.csv'
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")

coords= []
for line in file:
    currentline = line.split(",")
    coords.append(( float(currentline[1]), float(currentline[2]) ))

print(coords)

polyline.encode(coords)
```

Comment: thank you, that seemed to havee work as now im getting a TypeError: must be real number, not str, i guess i should convert it to int as the numbers are still being read as strings_

Comment: You're welcome!

If you change the input from a `String` to a `Float` I think that should resolve your issue. I updated my answer.